# How to avoid group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say there are two tables, one table has a column `name`, and the other has a column `occupation`. I'm trying to find out how many people have more than 6 occupations in my records. I've tried to `COUNT` the occupations, but the problem is, when I do, I need to `group by`. When I `group by` the `name`, the problem arises when there are two "Alex Jones", each having 4 occupations, and so the resulting `group by` gives me "Alex Jones: 8".

I'm not sure how I can avoid this, some advise would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results ,and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Updated the tags, but I did describe what the desired result is supposed to be @GordonLinoff

Comment: @JakeDrone, the reason why Gordon asked for some sample data is because it is very difficult to answer your question without understanding the structure of your data.  You say "one table has a column [name]" and "the other has a column [occupation]".  Since you're saying that you getting some results (but not what you want), then you must have some kind of query already written, which would potentially demonstrate other columns in the tables (eg. there is probably an [id] column, or similar, to identify each row).  That additional info is what will help someone point you in the right direction

Comment: @Craig I don't see why people make a big deal about everything around here, YFI answered my question without pretending that there is some huge ambiguity to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that when you group by "name" you end up grouping two names that are identical, but refer to different people, than your "name" column is not unique. Try using a combination of columns that make the group by unique or group by using a unique column.

You can do for example `group by name, other_column`, where other_column is a column that in conjunction with "name" identify uniquely the person. Or even better `group by personal_id`., if you have a unique column like a social security number, or something like that.

As another option, you can use window functions to count without grouping by. For example :

```
select 
... 
name, 
COUNT(occupation) OVER(PARTITION BY name) 
... 
from
my_table
```

You can learn how to use it from here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html